# How to fix the position for the text in the output C++,STL

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers, multimap

I need to print the original text in `DisplayOriginalText()` after finding `KnownWords` and `UnknownWords`. Everything is working perfectly fine but there is a little mistake in my output. The compiler places the last word of the original text to the first word of the `OriginalText`. I am giving an example in the output to make it more clear. Can someone figure out what is the issue and how to correct that ?

My output:

```
expensive this is my car and this is so much
```

Required output:

```
this is my car and this car is so much expensive
```

Note: This is just an example. Original text is an article for about 500 words.

Header file:

```
typedef map<string, vector<int> > WordMap;
typedef WordMap::iterator WordMapIter;

class WordStats
{
public:
    WordStats();
    void ReadDictionary();
    void DisplayDictionary();
    void ReadTxtFile();
    void DisplayKnownWordStats();
    void DisplayUnknownWordStats();
    void DisplayMostFreqKnownWords();
    void DisplayMostFreqUnknownWords();
    void DisplayOriginalText();
private:
    WordMap KnownWords;
    WordMap UnknownWords;
    set<string> Allwords;
    WordMapIter Paragraph;
    set<string> Dictionary;
    char Filename[256];

    //add your private fns here
    string parse_word(string word);
    void DisplayWordStats(WordMap &WMap);

};
```

My program:

```
void WordStats::DisplayOriginalText(){
    std::map<int,string> txt_map;
    std::map<int,string>::iterator mit;

    /// insert all known words
    for (WordMapIter it = KnownWords.begin(); it != KnownWords.end(); it++)
    for (vector<int>::iterator pos_it = it->second.begin(); pos_it != it- 
    >second.end(); pos_it++ )
        txt_map.insert(std::pair<int,string>(*pos_it, it->first) );


    /// insert all unknown words
    for (WordMapIter it = UnknownWords.begin(); it != UnknownWords.end(); 
    it++)
    for (vector<int>::iterator pos_it = it->second.begin(); pos_it != it- 
    >second.end(); pos_it++ )
        txt_map.insert(std::pair<int,string>(*pos_it, it->first) );

    cout << endl << "       - Original Text -" << endl << endl;

    for (mit = txt_map.begin(); mit != txt_map.end(); ++mit) 
    cout << mit->second << " ";

    cout << endl;   
}
```

Comment: I would use a debugger, but I am away from my development computer.  Could you help me out and use a debugger on your code?

Comment: okay, just tell me what do i need to do

Comment: Tried. Couldn't compile. No `main`. Missing headers. Heading out for a root beer.

Comment: I just added my header file

Comment: In order for me to tell you what to do, you would need to supply information, such as what platform, IDE, compiler and what debugger you have.  Search the internet for "how to debug small programs".

Comment: *Can someone figure out what is the issue and how to correct that ?* -- Asking someone else to debug the code for you, in my day, would be considered cheating.  You should learn to debug your own code -- if you write it, you should be able to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void WordStats::DisplayOriginalText(){
std::map<int,string> mtext;
std::map<int,string>::iterator miter;
vector<int>::iterator v_iter;

// inserting known words
for (Paragraph = KnownWords.begin(); Paragraph != KnownWords.end(); Paragraph++)
{
    for ( v_iter = Paragraph->second.begin(); v_iter != Paragraph->second.end(); v_iter++ )
    {
        mtext.insert(std::pair<int,string>(*v_iter, Paragraph->first) );
    }
}
/// inserting unknown words
for (Paragraph = UnknownWords.begin(); Paragraph != UnknownWords.end(); Paragraph++)
{
    for ( v_iter = Paragraph->second.begin(); v_iter != Paragraph->second.end(); v_iter++ )
    {
        mtext.insert(std::pair<int,string>(*v_iter, Paragraph->first) );
    }
}
cout <<"\n         ";
cout << "--- Original Text ---\n\n";

for (miter = mtext.begin(); miter != mtext.end(); ++miter) 
{
    cout << miter->second << " ";
}   
cout << endl;   
}
```

Comment: Tried to write this way. Use vector iterator after maps. Donot use WordMaps. Sorry for confusing statements. Just see the coding up there for more clearer answer.

Comment: You are legend.